# Como refatorar JS legado para implementar Testes Unitários?

Tags: javascript, testes-de-unidade, refatoração, jasmine, jest

Tenho um site em WordPress com muitos arquivos JS que não foram estruturados para serem testados - eles não foram escritos como módulos que podem ser importados nem existe um `app.js` que faça o carregamento de todos como num framework.

Os arquivos são somente compilados e minificados para uso no site, e eu quero começar a reformular pouco a pouco, à medida que vou fazendo a manutenção do site, adicionando testes para bug resolvidos e novas funcionalidades.

Todos os arquivos tem uma estrutura semelhante a:

```
( function( window ) {
    'use strict';

    var document = window.document;

    var objeto = { 
        params : {
            // etc
        },
        init: function() {
            // etc
        },
        outroMetodo: function() {
            // etc
        }

    }

    objeto.init();
} )(this);
```

Me sugeriram usar [Jest](http://jestjs.io/en/) e a configuração foi bem simples - o ambiente de testes está pronto - mas não sei como fazer para carregar os arquivos que precisam ser testados. Minha configuração atual no `package.json` é esta:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/tests/jest/**/*.test.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Imagino que seja preciso refatorar os arquivos de alguma forma para poder carrega-los no Jest antes de rodar os testes, mas como seria o jeito mais simples de permitir essa integração sem reescrever as funcionalidades? Tentei usar as configurações `setupFiles` e `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` mas como eu não tenho um arquivo único de setup me parece que não é a opção ideal.

Existe uma forma de incluir o arquivo a ser testado no começo de cada teste pra testar os métodos?

```
include( '/arquivo.js' ); // pseudocodigo

describe("Testes para arquivo.js", function() {
    it("testes do metodo X", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: O exemplo de codigo que deste é completamente privado, para conseguires testar isso, essa self-invoking function tem que fazer o assign desse "modulo" à window - de alguma manereia. Depois é só acederes ao `window.MODULE_NAME.metodo(arg)` para testes;

[checka o module pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) uma vez que esse codigo é bem parecido e o refactor não seria muito dificil :)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de quatro coisas pra melhorar seu código:

1. Um objetivo de como gostaria que seu código tivesse organizado (se começasse do zero, como faria?)
2. Todo código novo que criar deve obedecer a sua estrutura ideal (de acordo com o passo 1).
3. Conforme você toca em código antigo, você o refatora para que se encaixe na nova arquitetura.
4. Quando o código antigo estiver 80%—90% refatorado, você faz os outros 10%—20% numa tacada só.

Em JavaScript é comum que código legado esteja escrito como um script, o que é um problemão, pois quando importar o arquivo para teste ele vai executar um monte de código (e isso vai acontecer somente no momento da importação).

Pra resolver esse problema, sugiro que você refatore seu código pra separá-lo em duas partes: **Módulo** e **Script**

**Módulo** é um pedaço de código onde nada é executado. Nele você cria classes/funções e as exporta. **Script** é o tipo de código onde você faz módulos rodarem.

Exemplo:

Módulo:

```
// module/auth.js
export default class Auth {
  authenticate(username, password) {
    // restante do código...
  }
}
```

Script:

```
// script/auth.js
import Auth from '../module/auth';

$(() => {
  $('form').on('submit', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const username = $('#username').val()
    const password = $('#password').val()

    const auth = new Auth()
    const result = await auth.authenticate(username, password);
    // restante do código...
  });
});
```

Fazendo isso você consegue pelo menos testar `module/auth.js`, o que já é um ótimo começo!
Se quiser ir além, você também consegue definir a parte do jQuery (supondo que esteja usando jQuery) também em um "modscript":

Modscript:

```
// modscript/auth.js
import Auth from '../module/auth';

export default () => {
  $('form').on('submit', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const username = $('#username').val()
    const password = $('#password').val()

    const auth = new Auth()
    const result = await auth.authenticate(username, password);
    // restante do código...
  });
}
```

Script:

```
// script/auth.js
import execute from '../modscript/auth';
$(() => execute());
```

Dessa forma você agora também é capaz de testar as interações com o DOM. Como você já usa o Jest, então já tem o JSDom instalado e configurado.

Pra testar um "modscript" você fazer assim:

```
import execute from '../modscript/auth';

let originalAuthenticate;

beforeEach(() => {
  originalAuthenticate = auth.authenticate;
  auth.authenticate = jest.fn();
});

afterEach(() => {
  auth.authenticate = originalAuthenticate;
  $('body').html(''); // clean document
});

it('authenticates user upon form submission', () => {
  // Arrange
  $('body').append('<form><input id="username" /><input id="password" /></form>');
  $('#username').val('spam');
  $('#password').val('egg');
  auth.authenticate.mockResolvedValue(true);

  // Act
  execute();
  $('form').trigger('submit');

  // Assert
  expect(auth.authenticate.mock.calls).toContain(['spam', 'egg']);
  // outros expects...
});
```

Arquitetar testes de "modscripts" são consideravelmente mais complexos que arquitetar testes de módulos, mas eles dão mais confiança em relação às suas implementações porque a abrangência dos testes vai aumentar bastante.